# Error while installing pam-python-1.0.5

Tags: python, authentication, pam

When i run `make` command i receive following error

```
rm -f html/index.html && ln -s pam_python.html html/index.html
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/pam-python-1.0.5/doc'
make --directory src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/vagrant/pam-python-1.0.5/src'
gcc -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wsign-compare -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Werror -g -o ctest ctest.c -lpam
CFLAGS="-Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wsign-compare -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Werror" ./setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
building 'pam_python' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wsign-compare -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Werror -fPIC -DLIBPYTHON_SO="libpython2.6.so.1.0" -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c pam_python.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/pam_python.o
In file included from /usr/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h:6,
                 from /usr/include/python2.6/Python.h:8,
                 from pam_python.c:36:
/usr/include/python2.6/pyconfig-64.h:1043:1: error: "_XOPEN_SOURCE" redefined
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/security/_pam_macros.h:12,
                 from pam_python.c:32:
/usr/include/features.h:164:1: error: this is the location of the previous definition
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

System which i am using is `CentOs 6.7`.

Is there any other way to directly install pam module for python so that it generated `pam_python.so` in lib64/security directory.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest : Use the stable version = python-pam-1.8.2 .

The EL6 package : python-pam-1.8.2-2.el6.noarch.rpm ( 9.7kB )  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNQ1FrM1poTXR5Nmc/view?usp=sharing

Download the package, and ...

```
cd Downloads/
# yum install  python-pam-1.8.2-2.el6.noarch.rpm
```

---

EDIT : About the other "module" = pam-python 1.0.5 : Seems I found a solution →

```
cd pam-python-1.0.5/src/
python setup.py build
```

... and the file `build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/pam-python.so` was created.

Install : # `python setup.py install` ... the install text shows what's installed ... pam_python.py, pam_python.pyc,

```
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pam_python-1.0.5-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pam_python.so
```

---

Comment: It installs it successfully but does not create pam_python.so in the  lib directory ? 
Where it is created ?

Comment: Right, pam_pyhon is actually a quite different beast, it seems : Provides one file only → pam_python.so ,,, from the "1.0.1-src.rpm" (Suse).

Comment: python setup.py gives same warning in the question. Though it doesn't exit

Comment: @user2823667, did you get a result ? ( pam_python.so ). ... CentOS 6.7 : Please run # `yum update` ... and you have CentOS 6.8 ! ... Other suggestions : # `yum install gcc-c++` or/and # `yum reinstall gcc gcc-c++`